# Successive aggregation elasticsearch java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I've an a successive set of aggregations in a search request :

```
"aggs": {
    "nested_max": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "questionResponses"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "filter_max": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "questionResponses.key": "announcement.question.tri"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "agg_max": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "questionResponses.numericValue"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me translate this chunk of request to java code : 
what I've done (but doesn't work):

```
   NestedAggregationBuilder maxAggregation = 
AggregationBuilders.nested("nested_max", questionResponses)
                   .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.filter("filter_max", QueryBuilders.termQuery("announcement.question.tri", "announcement.question.tri")))
                   .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.max("agg_max").field("questionResponses.numericValue"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add agg_max sub aggregation to filter_max aggs.

```
filterMax = AggregationBuilders.filter(....);
aggMax = AggregationBuilders.max("agg_max")..;

NestedAggregationBuilder maxAggregation = 
AggregationBuilders.nested("nested_max", questionResponses)
                   .subAggregation(aggFilterMax.subAggregation(aggMax));
```